# On friction air question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

An object is released from a height of $50$ meters above the ground. Since its acceleration is $a(t)=g \ e^{-bt} \ m/s^2$ and $b=1/2 s^{-1}$, how many seconds will it hit the ground from the moment it is released?

My try:
$$\displaystyle v(t)=\int_{0}^{t} a(t) dt = \int_{0}^{t} g \ e^{-t/2} dt$$
$$=g\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{e^{t/2}}dt=-2ge^{-t/2}$$
$$x(t)=\int_{0}^{t} v(t) dt= \int_{0}^{t} -2ge^{-t/2} dt = 4ge^{-t/2}-4g$$
Since the height is $50$ meters
$$50=  4ge^{-t/2}-4g$$
$$t\approx -1.64327 s$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the integrals in the two extreme values, s.t. the velocity becomes

$v(t) - \underbrace{v_0}_{=0} = \dots = -2 \dfrac{g}{b} e^{-b t^*} \bigg|_{0}^{t} = 2 \dfrac{g}{b} \left[ 1 - e^{-b t} \right]$,

and then the position

$x(t) - x_0 = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{t} v(t^*) dt^*$.

I won't provide you the calculations, but only a hint to solve the problem: at the final time, when the system hits the ground, it has traveled $x(t_{fin})-x_0 = 50 \, m$. Evaluate the integral on the right and solve for $t_{fin}$ .

Comment: When the calculations are made it turns out about $t\approx 2.77533 \ s$. Sounds logical. Thank you sir.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't perform the computations, but I trust you

Comment: I did the calculation by assuming $x_0=0 \ m$, it takes $0$ from the place it left off and deducts $50$ from the point it left, am I right?

Comment: If I made the calc right, you have to solve the nonlinear equation $\Delta x = \dfrac{g}{b} \left[ t - \dfrac{1}{b} ( 1- e^{-bt}) \right]$. And if I did it right, the results should be approx $t \approx 4.35 \, s$

Comment: What is the $x_0$ sir?

Comment: $\Delta x = x(t) - x_0 = 50 \, m$ the height of the mass over the ground as the initial condition. You can solve the equation with a numerical method (fsolve, if you're familiar with Octave, Matlab, Python, or other interpreted programming language) or with a graphical method (draw the diagram of the function $f(t) = \dfrac{g}{b}\left[ t - \dfrac{1}{b} ( 1 - e^{-bt} ) \right]$ and find the value of $t$ where it reaches value = 50.

Comment: But $\Delta x=\int_{0}^{t} v(t') dt'= \int_{0}^{t} 2\frac{g}{b}\left(1-e^{-bt'}\right) dt' =2\frac{g}{b^2}\left(bt+e^{-bt}-1\right)$

Comment: You're right. I missed the 2 factor. So the result should be approximately $t \approx 2.18 \, s$.

Comment: Thank you for everything sir, have a good day! ♥